# Determine size of a view in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm dynamically *rendering* (as opposed to downloading) thumbnails for items displayed in a `RecyclerView`. The rendering should render those thumbnails at the size of the item (so there's no upscaling or downscaling).

I've tried calling measure() on the imageView in my `RecyclerView`.Adapter subclass's `onBindViewHolder` and `onViewAttachedToWindow` and in both cases, the measured size ( and actual size ) are reported as 0.

So, the trouble is simply, I can't figure out how to know what size to render my thumbnails at.

My best guess right now is to attach a listener to `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` and to render my thumbnails in that callback, but that seems awkward. Is that really the only way?

I can't find any method in `GridLayoutManager` or `RecyclerView` to simply ask, "how big will this child view be?"

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the measured size at `onBindViewHolder` is zero because most likely the view hasn't been measured and laid out yet.

The way I see it, you have two options.

Option 1: Kind of brute force.  I'll assume you have a vertically scrolling grid layout.  You get the width of the `RecyclerView`, you get the number of columns, divide the one by the other, and you get your image width.  From there you can probably figure out the height.  Now if you are doing margin gaps, multi-column spans or other exotic things, you may need to skip directly to the next option.

Option 2: Elegantly complicated.  You will need to make a special `ImageView` subclass that will do two main things:

- Receive a reference to an asynchronous task to render the image.
- Override `onMeasure()` to perform some special logic.  When `onMeasure()` is called, the width will be known, and the height will be "whatever size you want".  Before calling `super.onMeasure()` you will change the heightMeasureSpec to be an exact height based on the aspect ratio of your image.  Then you call `super.onMeasure()`, then kick off your render task.  The render task will have a reference to your `ImageView` object, so that the image can be loaded when the task is completed.

You create the render task in `onBindViewHolder` (where you will know which image you want) and assign it to the `ImageView`.  At the time the task is executed from `onMeasure()`, you will also know the size the image needs to be.

This solution -- although flexible -- obviously has a lot more moving parts and there's more ways that things can go wrong.

After you look at these, you may realize there actually is a third option:

Option 3.  Just render the image at a predefined size and let the `ImageView` scale it.  Any image distortion introduced by the scaling is probably not enough to warrant a herculean level of effort to render at the exact dimensions of the view.

Comment: Option 1 was the best intersection of good results and non-Herculean effort.  Thanks for the well-thought-out suggestions.